# Defining joint distribution of two uniform variables where one is bounded by the other

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, problem-solving, uniform-distribution, marginal-distribution

I want to know how to define the joint distribution between two continuous uniform random
variables. The first variable, X, is simply X ~ U(0, 1). The second variable, Y, can also vary between 0 and 1, but its bounded by the region defined by two lines: Y = X ± (1-k) where the constant k : [0, 1]. This results in a graph like this:

[image]

where k = 0.5, the blue line is the upper bound, the red is the lower bound, and the points represent random draws from X and Y. How do I define the joint distribution $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[We can](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Conditional_continuous_distributions) break the joint distribution into a product of marginal and conditional distributions:
$$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_{X}(x) f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x).$$

We have the marginal distribution for $X$:
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } 0 < x < 1,\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
and, letting $c = 1 - k$, the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ is a uniform on the interval with lower bound $$\max(0, x - c),$$ and upper bound $$\min(1, x + c).$$
Therefore,
$$f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) = \begin{cases}
\left(\min(1, x + c) - \max(0, x - c)\right)^{-1} & \text{if } \max(0, x - c) < y < \min(1, x + c),\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Multiplying these together we have
$$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\left(\min(1, x + c) - \max(0, x - c)\right)^{-1} & \text{if } 0 < x < 1 \text{ and } \max(0, x - c) < y < \min(1, x + c),\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$